# c++ getting weird crashes in my program

Tags: c++, arrays, char

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 0, skrb = 0, j = 0;
    char b, simboliai[2000];
    char zodis[50][20]; 
    char check[1][20] = {'f'};
    cout << "Prasome irasykite sakini: ";
    cin.getline(simboliai,sizeof(simboliai));
//----------------- Zodziu skaidymas ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i > -1; i++)
    {
        if ((simboliai[i] == 's' && simboliai[i++] == ' ') || (simboliai[i] == 's' && simboliai[i++] == '\n'))
        {
            check[0][a] = 't';
        }
        if (simboliai[i] == ' ')
        {
            a++;
        }
        else
        {
            zodis[i][a] = simboliai[i];
        }
        if (simboliai[i] == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    a = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (simboliai[a] == '.' || simboliai[a] == ',' || simboliai[a] == '!' || simboliai[a] == '?')
        {
            skrb++;
        }
        a++;
        if (simboliai[a] == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    a = 0;
    cout << "Jus ivedete tokius zodius kurie baigiasi raide 's'" << endl;
    while(1)
    {
        if (zodis[j][a] == 'Ì')
        {
            cout << '\n';
            a++;
        }
        if (check[0][a] == 't')
        {
            cout << zodis[j][a];
        }
        if (zodis[0][a] == 'Ì')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Pas jus yra (.','!'?) simboliu: " << skrb << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

Basically this program would work but that for part just ruins everything. It doesn't put characters one by one. And when I debug it shows that program have put symbol in its place but then there is Ì.
So it looks just like so 
input: word word
zodis[0][0] goes like wÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ zodis [1][0] goes oÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ and so on and it breaks. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i > -1; i++)` ...

Comment: Also since this is C++, do use `string` and not char arrays for strings.

Comment: `(simboliai[i] == 's' && simboliai[i++] == ' ')` unfortunately for you this is never going to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saying the for loop wouldn't put characters 1 by 1, it was in your "simboliai[i++] == ' '" logic. integer 'i' been incremented twice each loop when current character is 's' which mean it will be incremented from i=2 to i=4 if simboliai[i] = 's'. Use i+1 instead for your checking.

Comment: it should be incremented 3 times each loop since you check for simboliai[i] = 's' for two times.

Comment: Yes this did helped me. But it seems that char array works a bit different than other arrays with placement of symbols so I will need to work that out I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i > -1; i++)
{
   ...
}
```

is the main problem. There might be others but I don't look too closely for them.

The values of `i` will be 0, 1, 2. etc.
All of them are greater than -1.
The loop will go on until the value `i` reaches INT_MAX. (Not sure what happens when `i` is incremented at that time).

That is way larger than the size of the array `simboliai` anyway. Your program will access the array `simboliai` beyond valid limits and cause undefined behavior.

I think what you need is:

```
size_t len = strlen(simboliai);
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
   ...
}
```

**Other Problems**

1. Some of the errors result from the assumption that there is a newline character in `simboliai`. That assumption is not correct. `std::istream::getline` reads and discards the newline character.
2. If Google Translate is correct, `zodis` is supposed to contain a list of words. When you are iterating over the characters of `simboliai`, you need three counters.

   1. One to iterate over the characters of `simboliai`.
   2. One to keep track of the number words.
   3. One to keep track of the number of characters in the current word.

   Your `for` loop is not doing that.
3. When you are trying to access the contents of an array, you need to always write defensive code and make sure that you never access the array using out of bounds indices. In the last `while` loop, you are not doing that.
4. In the last `while` loop, you are incrementing `a` only in the first `if` block. If the conditional of that `if` statement evaluates to `false`, `a` never gets incremented and you get stuck in an infinite loop.
5. In the last loop you use `j` as an index but its value is initialized to `0` at the start of the function and never gets updated. It's not clear what the intent of the last `while` loop is. Hence, I can't say whether it's a bug but it sounds like it could be.

Here's a cleaned up version of your posted code with still a few unknowns.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a = 0, skrb = 0, j = 0;
   char b, simboliai[2000];
   char zodis[50][20]; 
   char check[1][20] = {'f'};
   cout << "Prasome irasykite sakini: ";
   cin.getline(simboliai,sizeof(simboliai));
   //----------------- Zodziu skaidymas ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   int word_counter = 0;
   a = 0;
   size_t len = std::strlen(simboliai);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      if ((simboliai[i] == 's' && simboliai[i+1] == ' ') || (simboliai[i] == 's' && simboliai[i+1] == '\0'))
      {
         check[0][a] = 't';
      }
      if (simboliai[i] == ' ')
      {
         zodis[word_counter][a] = '\0';
         a = 0;
         ++word_counter;
      }
      else
      {
         zodis[word_counter][a] = simboliai[i];
         ++a;
      }
   }

   a = 0;
   while ( simboliai[a] != '\0' )
   {
      if (simboliai[a] == '.' || simboliai[a] == ',' || simboliai[a] == '!' || simboliai[a] == '?')
      {
         skrb++;
      }
      a++;
   }

   a = 0;
   cout << "Jus ivedete tokius zodius kurie baigiasi raide 's'" << endl;
   while( j < 50 && a < 20 )
   {
      if (zodis[j][a] == 'Ì')
      {
         cout << '\n';
      }
      if (check[0][a] == 't')
      {
         cout << zodis[j][a];
      }
      if (zodis[0][a] == 'Ì')
      {
         break;
      }
      a++;
   }
   cout << "Pas jus yra (.','!'?) simboliu: " << skrb << endl;
   cin.ignore();
   cin.get();
}
```

Comment: There is a `break` condition in the loop body.

Comment: @Ari0nhh, that won't be reached since `istream::getline` reads and discards the newline character.

Comment: @R Sahu I know) But question author is most likely not, so he would not understand why his loop is infinite. `(simboliai[i] == 's' && simboliai[i++] == ' ')` is also pretty bad looking.

Comment: I put break for that cycle. So it stop at required condition. But issue is that im asked to make a code with char arrays. Program must read in words from user then print out words that ends with letter 's' and all it must be done using only char type.